# How to use image of a site to display at other page when site is private

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a Google Site which is private. I have announcement page where I do `post`...

I want to fetch the latest post image and want to display it at other page...

But I am getting problem that if site is private, I am not able to `fetch` that image from its `URL` and as well as with its content.

Code:

```
var page = SitesApp.getSite(domainName, sitename).getChildByName(announcementPageName)
var announcements = page.getAnnouncements();
var coll=[]
for(var i=0;i< announcements.length;i++){
    var announcementJson={title : announcements[i].getTitle(),
                          content : announcements[i].getTextContent(),
                          image : announcements[i].getAttachments()[0].getUrl()
                         }
coll.push(announcementJson)
}
```

When I used the `coll[i].image` in `"img src="""` tag of HTML, it did not give output.

How can I solve this?

My site is in a Google Apps Domain and the permission of site is either *private* or *person within domain*. I read somewhere that Google Sites encode the image URL, and if site is private then `post` tag will not be valid for encoded URL. If it is so, then what is alternative of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to work around the security settings of the domain and google. This may violate your employment agreement and local laws, so check with your domain administrator first.

Overall concept:

1. In a domain account, create an apps-script with a time-based trigger. This script will periodically capture the image you are interested in, and save it *somewhere*. (We'll assume that somewhere is the user's google drive, and that it is synchronized onto a pc using the same domain account.)
2. Outside of the domain account, another time-based script will get that image from *somewhere*, and put it *somewhere public*. This could easily be a python script running on the same pc that has the google docs sync; that script can check for the presence of a new copy of the image file, and copy it to a public location (such as a Dropbox account -- see [Python API](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1.zip)). Alternatively, your company may have a public web server that you can copy the file to.
3. Your external (non-domain) site need only refer to the image by its *somewhere public* URL (e.g. Dropbox).

I hope this helps get you started.